# Animation set for image view

Tags: android, android-animation

I want multiple animations to be played on the same ImageView. I'm using an animation set but it never fades in. But it does rotate. Can somebody tell me what I'm missing ?

```
    AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false mean dont share interpolators

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);
    iv.setAnimation(fadeIn);
    iv.startAnimation(fadeIn);


    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(800);

    s.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    s.addAnimation(anim);
    iv.startAnimation(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);
    fadeIn.setFillEnabled(true); // to apply setFillBefore and setFillAfter
    fadeIn.setFillBefore(true); // it means that at start of animation you set alpha="0"
    fadeIn.setFillAfter(false);
    iv.setAnimation(fadeIn);
    iv.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Also, in your styles you must remove `alpha="0"`

`AlphaAnimation` is working on your image as it is. So if you set `alpha="0"` it works between this `0`. If `alpha="1"` or without it (when style default is `alpha="1"`), it works between `0-1`.

Comment: I'll try that out but I probably should have mentioned it - The fadeIn animation works when it is the only animation.